# How to find the rows having values between -1 and 1 in a given numpy 2D-array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `np.array` of shape `(15,3)`.

```
final_vals = array([[  37,  -84, -143],
       [  29,    2,   -2],
       [ -18,   -2,    0],
       [  -3,    6,    0],
       [ 361,   -5,    2],
       [ -23,    4,    8],
       [   0,   -1,    0],
       [  -1,    1,    0],
       [  62,  181,   83],
       [-193,  -14,   -2],
       [  42, -154,  -92],
       [  16,  -13,    1],
       [ -10,   -3,    0],
       [-299,  244,  110],
       [ 223, -237, -110]])
```

am trying to find the rows whose element values are between -1 and 1.In the array printed above ROW-6 and ROW-7 are target/result rows.

I tried,

```
result_idx = np.where(np.logical_and(final_vals>=-1, final_vals<=1))
```

which returns,

```
result_idx = (array([ 2,  3,  6,  6,  6,  7,  7,  7, 11, 12], dtype=int64),
              array([2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2], dtype=int64))
```

***I want my program to return only row numbers***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the absolute value of all elements, and check which rows's elements are smaller or equal to `1`. Then use [`np.flatnonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html) to find the indices where all columns fullfil the condition:

```
np.flatnonzero((np.abs(final_vals) <= 1).all(axis=1))
```

**Output**

```
array([6, 7], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: This works. just need to add one **(** after  np.flatnonzero.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this based on your approach is to find the truth value of each element and then use [`numpy.all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) for each row. Then `numpy.where` gets you what you want.

```
mask = (final_vals <= 1) * (final_vals >= -1)
np.where(np.all(mask, axis=1))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
np.where(np.all((-1<=final_vals) & (final_vals<=1),axis=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [np.argwhere](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html):

```
r = np.logical_and(final_vals <= 1, final_vals >=-1)
result = np.argwhere(r.all(1)).flatten()

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[6 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using `pandas`, 
you can achieve the row with following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(final_vals)
temp= ((df>=-1) & (df<=1 )).product(axis=1)
rows = temp[temp!=0].keys()
rows
```

At first it check numbers that are between -1 and +1  and then check rows(with axis=1) that all values accept the condition.

and the result is:
`Int64Index([ 6, 7], dtype='int64')`

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple list comprehension:

```
[ i for i, row in enumerate(final_vals) if all([ e >= -1 and e <= 1 for e in row ]) ]
#=> [6, 7]
```